# How to replace multiplie "\n" to "\n\t\t\t" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Okey, I need some help with a code in Javascript.

If this is the input of a string: `"\nLorem ipsum\nMid magnis\nTristique mauris proin"`

I want this as output: `"\n\t\t\tLorem ipsum\n\t\t\tMid magnis\n\t\t\tTristique mauris proin"`

So I tried to do this function:

```
var text = function (texts) {
    var str = texts;
    return str.replace("\n", "\n\t\t\t");
}
------> "\n\t\t\tLorem ipsum\nMid magnis\nTristique mauris proin"
```

And it takes only the first "\n" and replace it with "\n\t\t\t".

So please, can I have som help?
Cheers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex with the global flag:

```
"\nLorem ipsum\nMid magnis\nTristique mauris proin".replace(/\n/g, '\n\t\t\t');
```